# Training logistic regression with tf.GradientTape() can't converge

Tags: python, logistic-regression, tensorflow2.0

I trained logistic regression with tf.GradientTape but it can't converge

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

xs = np.array([[1, 1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1.1]])
ys = np.array([1, 0, 0])

def lr_model():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2))
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)

    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model = lr_model()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(xs, ys, batch_size=3, epochs=10)

for i in range(10):
    print(i, history.history['loss'][i], history.history['accuracy'][i])
```

> It converges and the results:
>       0 1.04525887966156 0.0
>       1 0.9557339549064636 0.0
>       2 0.8753216862678528 0.0
>       3 0.8033372759819031 0.0
>       4 0.7390384674072266 0.0
>       5 0.6816689968109131 0.6666667
>       6 0.6304909586906433 1.0
>       7 0.5848075151443481 1.0
>       8 0.5439766049385071 1.0
>       9 0.5074175596237183 1.0

But I wanna write my training flow listed as below:

```
train_loss = keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_acc = keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

model = lr_model()
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1)

def train_step(data, labels):    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    data = tf.cast(data, tf.float32)
    pred = model(data)
    loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(labels, pred)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_acc(labels, pred)

for i in range(100):
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_acc.reset_states()
    train_step(xs, ys)

    if i % 10 == 0:
    print(i, train_loss.result().numpy(),train_acc.result().numpy())
```

> It can't converge as the previous example and I don't know why
>       0 0.7586897 1.0
>       10 0.6607897 1.0
>       20 0.64341 0.6666667
>       30 0.63867164 0.6666667
>       40 0.63722247 0.6666667
>       50 0.63676286 0.6666667
>       60 0.63661444 0.6666667
>       70 0.636566 0.6666667
>       80 0.63654995 0.6666667
>       90 0.6365447 0.6666667

What's the problem with my codes? And how should I modify my training codes by tf.GradientTape to converge as keras compile/fit does? Thanks

Comment: Answer my own question, the codes can be resolved as well by replacing pred = model(data) with pred = tf.squeeze(model(data))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tf.enable_eager_execution()

xs = np.array([[1, 1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1.1]])
ys = np.array([1., 0., 0.])

def get_model():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2,))
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


# Without Gradient Tape
model = get_model()    
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xs, ys, batch_size=3, epochs=50)

# With Gradient Tape
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_acc = keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
model = get_model()    

for i in range(50):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        xs_ = tf.cast(xs, tf.float32)
        ys_ = tf.cast(ys.reshape(-1,1), tf.float32)

        pred = model(xs_)

        loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(ys_, pred)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables) 
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

        print (train_acc(ys_, pred))
        #print (tf.math.reduce_sum(loss))
```

Comment: I modify my codes as train_step(xs, ys.reshape(-1, 1)), and it did work, thanks so much!